# Magento2 How to get tailwind css styles in phtml file of custom module in Hyva theme

Tags: magento2, hyva-themesmagento2-default-theme

I was working on a custom module for hyva theme compatibility but can't get any tailwind styles in phtml file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not seeing Tailwind CSS styles being applied to your custom module's templates in a Hyva theme for Magento 2, there are a few potential reasons why this might be happening:

**1**.**Tailwind CSS Integration:** Ensure that Tailwind CSS is properly integrated into your Hyva theme. This typically involves installing Tailwind CSS via npm or another package manager, configuring it to generate a CSS file, and then including that CSS file in your theme's layout or template files.

**2**.**Template Inclusion:** Confirm that your .phtml file is properly included in the page where you expect to see the Tailwind CSS styles. Check the layout XML files (layout/*.xml in your custom module or theme) to make sure the template is being added to the appropriate block.

**3**.**CSS Class Usage:** Ensure that you're using Tailwind CSS classes correctly in your .phtml file. Tailwind CSS classes should be added directly to HTML elements in your template. For example:

```
<div class="bg-blue-500 text-white p-4">
    This is a container with Tailwind CSS styles.
</div>
```

for tailwind css cass list : https://tailwind.build/classes

for more details you can check this, https://webkul.com/blog/working-with-tailwindcss-in-hyva-theme/